# What is the meaning of "is out cleaning houses, trying to make a fortune"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "is out cleaning houses, trying to make a fortune" in the following sentences(Source: Keeping House illustrated by WENDY SMITH ),

> "I am quite worn out," she told the cat and the parrot one day. "The
>   house is so topsy-turvy that I have decided to send for Robin
>   Puckertucker, the Wonder HouseKeeper."
>
> She looked up the number and telephoned immediately. "This is a
>   recorded message," said a voice. "Robin Puckertucker
>   **is out cleaning houses, trying to make a fortune.** Please leave your name and address when you hear the tone and Robin will rush round
>   early tomorrow morning. And please make sure you don't spoil things by
>   trying to tidy up yourself!"

?

Does "Robin Puckertucker is out cleaning houses, trying to make a fortune" mean "Robin Puckertucker is out. and he is cleaning houses. and he is trying to make money" ?

Does "Please make sure you don't spoil things by trying to tidy up yourself!
" mean "Do not just try to clean yourself, but also clean things" or "Do not try to clean things by yourself, but let Robin clean it up"?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.

Comment: For your second question, it's the second interpretation: Do not try to clean things by yourself, but let Robin clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first phrase, 'is out cleaning houses, trying to make a fortune' means that he is not at home because he is trying to make money by cleaning houses. You are correct about that. It is strange that Robin uses the word 'fortune'. The word 'fortune' means a huge some of money, not just the amount that somebody would normally make by cleaning houses. There is something nonsensical or sarcastic about the use of this word instead of a more neutral word like, 'money'.

The next part of the message is also unusual. As you have recognized, Robin is advising the caller not to clean up, but rather to wait until he arrives. The unusual part is that he says, 'Don't spoil things by trying...'. To 'spoil things' in this case means to create a bad situation. It's not clear what Robin means by this. Robin might saying that the caller would make the situation worse than it is by tidying up, as if Robin thinks he will do a better job than the caller, or it will be harder for Robin to clean if the caller 'tries' to do it and does it badly. Or he might be telling the caller not to prevent him from making his 'fortune' by doing it before he can come.